# Tratar CSV con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Tengo un fichero csv con 25 columnas y con un pequeño programita en python me gustaria coger los valores de 5 columnas y generar un nuevo fichero csv con esta informacion, con estas 5 columnas.

¿Me podeis ayudar?

Gracias de antemano

Un saludo
Juan Carlos

Comment: Creo que [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-a-csv-file-with-csv-module) puede ayudarte mucho. Es lo mismo que estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer esto el primer paso es guardar el fichero desde excel en UTF-8 format:

[image: Formato]

Después instalas pandas (pip install pandas)

y puedes usar este mismo código:

```
import pandas as pd

tabla = pd.read_csv('tabla.csv',delimiter=';')
```

el delimiter lo pongo con ';' ya que mi csv está separado por ';'

Finalmente lo guardas fácil de esta manera:

```
tabla_a_guardar = tabla[['columna1', 'columna2', 'columna3','columna25']]

tabla_a_guardar.to_csv('fichero_salida.csv',sep=';',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si los registros tiene encabezados lo puedes hacer así

```
import csv

salida = open("resultados.txt","w") 

with open("file.txt", "r")  as f:
    lector = csv.DictReader(f)
    for registro in lector:
        if registro["name_col"] in ["1","2"]:
             dato1 = [registro["name_col"]]
             dato2 = [registro["name_col2"]]
             data = dato1 + dato2
             salida.write(",".join(data) + "\n")

salida.close()
```

Si no tiene encabezados en la parte de lector quedaría asi

```
lector = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
```

Y la selección de registros sería por su posición

```
registro[0] in condición:
```